# How do i check for discord owner and permission and if they have those specific roles or not at one if condition?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'f been trying to make all of this in one if statement condition but whenever i add more using or operator something breaks.
example:
if i have the roles check only it tells me if i can use the commands or not
when i add to check if they have perms adminstrator or is ownership it always tells me i cant use the command even though i am ownership or i have adminstrator
dont mind the database part about the admin and mod roles

```js
if(!message.member.hasPermission(["ADMINISTRATOR"]) || !message.guild.owner || !message.member.roles.cache.some(x=>[...settings.roles.adminRole, ...settings.roles.modRole].includes(x.id))) {
      return message.channel.send("You do not have permission to perform this command!")
    } else {
      message.channel.send("yes u do")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking negatives with `||`, you should either switch to positives or `&&`:

```js
const member = message.member;

//just copying your snippet but this is a weird way to do, why are deconstructing those properties? 
//They shouldnt't be arrays just strings of the roles id
const settingRoles = [...settings.roles.adminRole, ...settings.roles.modRole];

if(
  member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") ||
  //check the id of the owner instead of checking if there is a owner 
  message.guild.ownerID === member.id ||
  member.roles.cache.find(x => settingRoles.includes(x.id))
){ 
  console.log("Member has permission");
} else {
  console.log("Member does not");
}
```